# Error creating PDF document with php

Tags: php, pdf

i got this code from an ebook o'oreilly programmming PHP about creating pdf document
i run wamp server on windows 7 and PDFLIB is enabled

```
    $pdf = pdf_new();
    pdf_open_file($pdf);
    pdf_set_info($pdf,'Creator','hello.php');
    pdf_set_info($pdf,'Author','Rasmus Lerdorf');
    pdf_set_info($pdf,'Title','Hello world (PHP)');
    pdf_begin_page($pdf,612,792);
    $font = pdf_findfont($pdf,'Helvetica-Bold','host',0);
    pdf_setfont($pdf,$font,38.0);
    pdf_show_xy($pdf,'Hello world!',50,700);
    pdf_end_page($pdf);
    pdf_set_parameter($pdf, "openaction", "fitpage");
    pdf_close($pdf);
    $buf = pdf_get_buffer($pdf);
    $len = strlen($buf);
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header("Content-Length: $len");
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=hello.pdf');
    echo $buf;
    pdf_delete($pdf);
```

but when ever i run it, i get the error

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDFlibException' with message 'pdf_open_file() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given' in C:\wamp\www\phpPdf\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\phpPdf\index.php(3): pdf_open_file(Resource id #2) #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\phpPdf\index.php on line 3
```

Comment: You need to add a second parameter to the call in line 2 of your example code.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means exactly what it says: "pdf_open_file() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given"

You need to give it a file name as a second parameter.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-open-file.php

Aside, the documentation also states that pdf_open_file is a deprecated function, so you should be using: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-begin-document.php

Comment: please can someone just provide a simple code to create a hello world pdf document that will run using pdfLIb 5.0